# Subset numeric data using wildcards?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, subset

I need to filter a dataset according to site ID. 
Essentially, I want to select all site IDs that end in 01. 
The site IDs are 6 digits in length. For example:

```
myData <- data.frame(ID = c(202001, 202002, 202003, 203001), someData = c(10, 20, 30, 40))
```

Can I use wildcards on numeric (or integer) data, something like:

```
filter(myData, ID = ****01)
```

Comment: `myData[grepl("01$", myData$ID), ]` should do it

Comment: Guessing at the dplyr translation -  `filter(mydata, grepl("01$", ID) )`  ?

Comment: thanks for the dplyr translation. part of what gets so confusing is all the various ways to 'skin a cat' in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grepl()` (and other regular expression matching functions) with the regular expression `01$`.  The `$` signifies that we want the matching to start at the end of the string.

```
myData[grepl("01$", myData$ID), ]
#       ID someData
# 1 202001       10
# 4 203001       40
```

@thelatemail has one *dplyr* method in the comments, also using `grepl()`.

```
filter(myData, grepl("01$", ID))
```

And speaking of ways to skin a cat

```
filter(myData, substr(ID, 5, 7) == "01")
#       ID someData
# 1 202001       10
# 2 203001       40
```